# Need help with limits going to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

Going into my Calculus final and there I'm having some issues with limits going to infinity and problems that are to the power of $x$.

Here is a problem I came across while studying which I'm pretty sure I messed up on.

**Compute the following limit (a calculator answer is not sufficient):**

$$\lim _{x\to\infty}(1+\sin(5/x))^x$$

**Here's what I did:**

First I set the formula to:

$e^{x\ln(1+\sin(5/x))}$

### and figured then that if I find the limit for $x\ln(1+\sin(5/x))$ then I could solve the problem

So with that being said:

$f(x) = x\ln(1+\sin(5/x))
     = \ln(1+\sin(5/x))/(1/x)$ (honestly don't know how I got $1/x$, I just saw in a similar problem someone do that.

Then I got the derivative of it

so $f'(x) = (1/(1+\sin(5/x) (-5/x^2)\cos(5/x))/(-1/x^2)$

then I got rid of the $1/x^2$ by multiplying it by $x^2/1$, which would make $-1$ (if I'm correct?)

after multiplying the $-1$ into $-5/x^2$ I did the same thing with that, which then gave me

$5\cos(5/x)/(1+\sin(5/x)) = (5\cdot 1)/(1+0)= 5/1=5$

I then put $5$ into $e$ to make the final answer $e^5$.

Was this right? sorry if my formatting is bad, still am new to this. If i was wrong where did I mess up? This is one of the concepts im struggling with and am trying to nail it before my final hits.

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Just a note --  to put a factor in the denominator, simply divide it by its reciprocal; that is $$ax=\dfrac{a}{\frac1x}.$$

Comment: @AndrewChin Thanks that explains a lot, so in essence for my problem the x gets canceled out by the 1/x but everything else stays?

Comment: The rewriting of the expression is solely for the purpose of applying L'Hopital's Rule.  I'll write an answer.

Comment: @AndrewChin thank you so much im so stuck with this concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\sin\left(\frac5x\right)\right)^x.$$

The expression inside the limit (as you have done) can be written as $$\left(1+\sin\left(\frac5x\right)\right)^x=e^{x\log(1+\sin\left(5/x\right)}.$$

As such, we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x\log(1+\sin\left(5/x\right)}= e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log(1+\sin\left(5/x\right))}.$$

Focusing on the limit in the exponent, we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log(1+\sin(5/x))=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+\sin(5/x))}{\frac1x}\overset{\text{L'H}}{=}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1+\sin(5/x)}\cdot\cos(5/x)\cdot-\frac{5}{x^2}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{5\cos(5/x)}{1+\sin(5/x)}=5.$$

Therefore, we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\sin\left(\frac5x\right)\right)^x=e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log(1+\sin\left(5/x\right))}=e^5.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\sin\left(\frac ax\right)\right)^x=\lim_{y\to 0}\left(1+\sin(y)\right)^{\frac a y}$$

So
$$A=\left(1+\sin(y)\right)^{\frac a y}\implies \log(A)={\frac a y}\log\left(1+\sin(y)\right)\sim a \frac {\sin(y)}y\sim a\implies A\sim e^a$$

Comment: I like very much your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano. Thank you !